# How to save in a single post two table OnetoOne - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    TYPES = (('A', 'Administrador'), ('P', 'Persona'), ('C', 'Corporativo'), ('E', 'Emprendedor'), ('R', 'Reciclador'))

    login_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPES, blank=True, null=True)
    picture_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class EcoUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='eco_user')
    document = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    ubigeo = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

In which when I want to add a **User** it is also saved in **EcoUser**

I thought that putting together in the **serializer** the two models and using a generic of **create** would work like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    eco_user = EcoUser.objects.filter(user_id=instance.id)[0]
    representation['document'] = eco_user.document
    representation['phone_number'] = eco_user.phone_number
    representation['ubigeo'] = eco_user.ubigeo
    representation['address'] = eco_user.address
    return representation


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id',
              'username',
              'password',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'email',
              'login_type',
              'account_type',
              'picture_url',
              'is_deleted'
              )
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': False}}
```

however, it only served to **list** but not to **create**.
this is my **viewset**:

```
class EcoUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.exclude(is_deleted=True)
    pagination_class = None


    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:
                data = request.data
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response({"status": True, "results": "Datos guardados correctamente"},
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except ValidationError as err:
                return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can I also save the Ecouser data in a single post?

**UPDATE**
json send example:

```
{
  username: "demo",
  firstname: "demin",
  lastname: "demon"
  login_type: "0",
  #ecouser fields
  account_type: "A",
  document: "74578778",
  phone_number: "54545445",
  ubigeo: "32114",
}
```

Comment: Have you happened to have seen this? https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Can you add sample JSON you wish to send?

Comment: Yes, update my question. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two serializer, one for User and another for EcoUser.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (your desire fields)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        #codes


class EcoUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = EcoUser
        fields = (
           'user',
           other fields
        )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        #codes
```

then write a view for EcoUserSerializer